# How to use Codemod(Next.js)? Invalid transform choice

Tags: reactjs, next.js, npx

I tried to apply codemod on my pages(index.js is inside).

```
 npx @next/codemod pages
npx: installed 440 in 15.252s
Invalid transform choice, pick one of:
- name-default-component
- withamp-to-config
- url-to-withrouter
```

Directory structure

```
node_modules
package.json
package-lock.json
pages
```

How to run codemod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a valid `transform` before your `path`.

From [Next.js codemod](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/codemods) documentation:

> **Usage**
>
> `npx @next/codemod <transform> <path>`
>
> - `transform` - name of transform, see available transforms below.
> - `path` - files or directory to transform
> - `--dry` Do a dry-run, no code will be edited
> - `--print` Prints the changed output for comparison